# I can't install mysqlclient using `pip install mysqlclient` command

Tags: python, mysql, pip, python-venv

Here is the console log after ran `pip install mysqlclient` command.

`(venv) Yu:sagemaker-modeltraining lee$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz (88 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: '/Volumes/Work Series/bloc-x/sagemaker/sagemaker-modeltraining/venv/bin/python' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_bfe6faaff6334a44b5df618fa8de82f2/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_bfe6faaff6334a44b5df618fa8de82f2/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-lnpozcvn
cwd: /private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_bfe6faaff6334a44b5df618fa8de82f2/
Complete output (15 lines):
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
/bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_bfe6faaff6334a44b5df618fa8de82f2/setup.py", line 15, in 
metadata, options = get_config()
File "/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_bfe6faaff6334a44b5df618fa8de82f2/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
libs = mysql_config("libs")
File "/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_bfe6faaff6334a44b5df618fa8de82f2/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
OSError: mysql_config not found
mysql_config --version
mariadb_config --version
mysql_config --libs
----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/df/59cd2fa5e48d0804d213bdcb1acb4d08c403b61c7ff7ed4dd4a6a2deb3f7/mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=f6ebea7c008f155baeefe16c56cd3ee6239f7a5a9ae42396c2f1860f08a7c432 (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.2.tar.gz (88 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: '/Volumes/Work Series/bloc-x/sagemaker/sagemaker-modeltraining/venv/bin/python' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_850f20e68f9b4a9c8db506f4494ef12b/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_850f20e68f9b4a9c8db506f4494ef12b/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-cl3w1t3z
cwd: /private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_850f20e68f9b4a9c8db506f4494ef12b/
Complete output (12 lines):
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
/bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_850f20e68f9b4a9c8db506f4494ef12b/setup.py", line 15, in 
metadata, options = get_config()
File "/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_850f20e68f9b4a9c8db506f4494ef12b/setup_posix.py", line 65, in get_config
libs = mysql_config("libs")
File "/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_850f20e68f9b4a9c8db506f4494ef12b/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
OSError: mysql_config not found
----------------------------------------
enter code here

..........

..........

WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6b/ba/4729d99e85a0a35bb46d55500570de05b4af10431cef174b6da9f58a0e50/mysqlclient-1.3.1.tar.gz#sha256=3549e8a61f10c8cd8eac6581d3f44d0594f535fb7b29e6090db3a0bc547b25ad (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.0.tar.gz (76 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: '/Volumes/Work Series/bloc-x/sagemaker/sagemaker-modeltraining/venv/bin/python' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_c4c84c03c6d84e2ba49d8978d8464e37/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_c4c84c03c6d84e2ba49d8978d8464e37/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-x9o75gw4
cwd: /private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_c4c84c03c6d84e2ba49d8978d8464e37/
Complete output (10 lines):
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_c4c84c03c6d84e2ba49d8978d8464e37/setup.py", line 17, in 
metadata, options = get_config()
File "/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_c4c84c03c6d84e2ba49d8978d8464e37/setup_posix.py", line 47, in get_config
libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
File "/private/var/folders/84/_mv3wv4d54ddl73qj3g3p_nw0000gn/T/pip-install-l1iepknb/mysqlclient_c4c84c03c6d84e2ba49d8978d8464e37/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
OSError: mysql_config not found
----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/91/bdfe808fb5dc99a5f65833b370818161b77ef6d1e19b488e4c146ab615aa/mysqlclient-1.3.0.tar.gz#sha256=06eb5664e3738b283ea2262ee60ed83192e898f019cc7ff251f4d05a564ab3b7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 1.3.10, 1.3.11rc1, 1.3.11, 1.3.12, 1.3.13, 1.3.14, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0rc3, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.2.post1, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient
`

my python version is 3.9.
I was going to use mysql database for my django backend.

here is the setting

DATABASES = {

```
   'default': {

       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',

       'NAME': 'messagebird',

       'USER': 'root',

       'PASSWORD': 'messagebird',

       'HOST': '127.0.0.1',

       'PORT': '3306',

   }
```

}

I am not sure why this issue happens.

screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtbm6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eaucf.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/` you can simply go in here and use `Ctrl+F` to find mysqlclient and download it for your machine now use `pip install wheel` the wheel once installed is available to run from the command line `python -m wheel install path_to_the_downloaded_wheel_file` now most probably the module will be installed

Comment: (venv) Yu:sagemaker-modeltraining lee$ pip install wheel

Collecting wheel

  Downloading wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)

Installing collected packages: wheel

Successfully installed wheel-0.36.2

(venv) Yu:sagemaker-modeltraining lee$ python -m wheel install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl 

usage: __main__.py [-h] {unpack,pack,convert,version,help} ...
__main__.py: error: invalid choice: 'install' (choose from 'unpack', 'pack', 'convert', 'version', 'help')

(venv) Yu:sagemaker-modeltraining lee$


here is the result. still issue

Comment: can you provide me with a screen shot

Comment: `pip install path_to_the_downloaded_wheel_file` or `python -m pip install path_to_the_downloaded_wheel_file`

Comment: consider using this

Comment: added screenhot to thie post

Comment: `pip install path_to_the_downloaded_wheel_file` or `python -m pip install path_to_the_downloaded_wheel_file`

What was the result using these

Comment: (venv) Yu:sagemaker-modeltraining lee$ python -m pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl 
ERROR: MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
(venv) Yu:sagemaker-modeltraining lee$ pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl 
ERROR: MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: it seems like you didn't download the wheel supported for ur os

Comment: I am using Mac OS, could you let me know the link to download?

Comment: i think this would be helpful https://ruddra.com/install-mysqlclient-macos/ for mac users

Answer (score 1):

Pls try using following command lines
pip install path_to_the_downloaded_wheel_file
or
python -m pip install path_to_the_downloaded_wheel_file